# after a merge down between a parent and child stream,if I rollback a specific folder, I cant see the mergedown option anymore between the two streams

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate

In my local stream workplace, I first did a merge down from a parent stream and then used rollback to revert the merge down on a specific folder.

The rollback worked on that folder, however since the child dev stream and the parent stream are different again, I dont see a merge down option again (say I want to merge down the two streams again).

Why cant I see the merge down option again?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by rollback? Did you revert the merge prior to submit? Or did you submit the merge and then submit a compensating change?

Comment: Hi Bryan. I submitted the merge first . Then I did a rollback on one of the merged folder.

Comment: Since you submitted the merge, you've told Perforce that the changes from the parent stream are included in your child stream. The fact that you later submitted a compensating changelist to rollback those changes adds additional history to your child stream, but doesn't change the fact that all the changes from the parent stream were successfully merged and submitted into your child stream. That is, the rollback didn't remove the history of the merge down; it added new history about a compensating change in the child stream.